# How to select multiple layers in Meshlab

Tags: mesh, meshlab

I have 20 layers of `obj` files. I want to set part of them visible while others invisible.

It's not convenient to set it one by one. Is there a easy way to select multiple layers at the same time and change their visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use the 'SubString match' parameter under 'Change visibility of layer(s)'.

For example, if your files are named mesh-01.obj to mesh-20.obj, you could use a 'SubString match' value of 'mesh-0' to target files 1 to 9 etc

Answer (score 2):

This keyboard shortcut may do the trick:
Press `control`/`command` + the eye button on some layer, and it will toggle visibility for all other layers